# get limited numbers of data with yii2

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I want to get limited numbers of data from database using Yİİ2. I fetched all the record by writing this:

```php
$departures = ArrayHelper::map(
    TourDeparture::find()->all(),
    'id',
    'tour_id'
);
```

I tried to use `limit(5)`, so that I can get only 5 rows. But I could not. Still, I get the all the rows in the table. How can I achieve that?

Updated: Here is my tourdeparture model

```
class TourDeparture extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
```

{

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'tour_departure';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['tour_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'price_1adult', 'price_2adult', 'price_3adult', 'price_child', 'price_baby', 'min_guests', 'max_guests', 'status', 'required_min_guest'], 'required'],
        [['tour_id', 'min_guests', 'max_guests', 'status', 'required_min_guest'], 'integer'],
        [['start_date', 'end_date'], 'safe'],
        [['price_1adult', 'price_2adult', 'price_3adult', 'price_child', 'price_baby'], 'number'],
        [['tour_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Tour::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['tour_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'tour_id' => 'Tour ID',
        'start_date' => 'Start Date',
        'end_date' => 'End Date',
        'price_1adult' => 'Price 1adult',
        'price_2adult' => 'Price 2adult',
        'price_3adult' => 'Price 3adult',
        'price_child' => 'Price Child',
        'price_baby' => 'Price Baby',
        'min_guests' => 'Min Guests',
        'max_guests' => 'Max Guests',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'required_min_guest' => 'Required Min Guest',
    ];
}

/**
 * Gets query for [[Tour]].
 *
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTour()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Tour::className(), ['id' => 'tour_id']);
}

/**
 * Gets query for [[TourReservations]].
 *
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTourReservations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TourReservation::className(), ['tour_departure_id' => 'id']);
}
```

}

Comment: Add the code that includes the `limit` method, what you are saying should work.

Comment: $departures = ArrayHelper::map(
    TourDeparture::find()->limit(5),
    'id',
    'tour_id'
);   I wrote it like above. but ı got all the record

Comment: Does your class inherit from \yii\db\ActiveRecord?

Comment: ı am beginner in yii. But I guess  there is no active record in my controller

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $departures = ArrayHelper::map( TourDeparture::find()->limit(5), 'id',
> 'tour_id' );
> ```
>
> I wrote it like above. but ı got all the record

I'm surprised your code worked at all!  You are passing the `Query` class into the `map` function. `ArrayHelper::map` is expecting an array and needs the query to be executed using the `->all()`. `->limit(5)` just adds a new term to the SQL query.

```
$departures = ArrayHelper::map( TourDeparture::find()->limit(5)->all(), 'id', 'tour_id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

for retrieve the first 5 rows should be

```
TourDeparture::find()->orderBy("id")->limit(5)->all()
```

Comment: still cant get 5 rows

Comment: seems weird  ..  check better   try var_dump the content  of  TourDeparture::find()->orderBy("id")->limit(5)->all()  and ebventually add   a proper data sample and your actual result ..

Comment: update your question and add  the TourDeparture model class code

Comment: I added the tourdeparture model

Comment: the model is derived  by the ActiveRecord class  so  the query provided shoudl return 5 record .. try var_dump the real result  .

Comment: I get the all records as an  array. Btw I put the var_dump in my view file. Am I doing right?

Answer (score 0):

> The code you shared didn't do the limit(5). Anyway, I believe it is caused by the array map,
> you may try to simulate the changes as below

```
$q = TourDeparture::find()->select(['id', 'tour_id'])->limit(5)->asArray()->all();

\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($q, $depth = 10, $highlight = true);
```

> For the above, records selected in array form, before array map.

> After array map, from here you can compare the changes.

```
$departures = ArrayHelper::map(
                 $q,
                 'id',
                 'tour_id'
              );

\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($departures, $depth = 10, $highlight = true);
```